# CentOS - Yum - Specify Mirror

Tags: centos, yum, mirror

Is it possible to specify a mirror for YUM to target when doing updates? I've noticed on my CentOS 6.2 servers that it takes up to a minute for YUM to respond from a given command. I did some Googling and found that YUM reads from a timedhosts.txt file, so I viewed the contents and it was pretty nasty. There were 49 lines, 32 of which had a value of 99999999999, which I assume to be a timeout.

There has to be a way for me to specify a mirror I know would be lightning fast (being from SoCal I would like to use http://mirrors.usc.edu/.

Comment: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/red-hat-fedora-linux/55408-how-configure-yum-repositories.html#post303954

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from disabling the default repos and adding an entry that points  to the specific server you want to use.  For example:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
baseurl=http://mirrors.usc.edu/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
priority=1

[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
baseurl=http://mirrors.usc.edu/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
priority=1
```

Comment: which file is this? yum.repos.d ?

Answer (score 4):

Do you have the fastest-mirror plugin installed? 
[centos wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/FastestMirror)
You could edit the base link, in /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo, to reflect the repo you would like. I am not sure this is best though.[similiar to how this was done with the local repo](http://www.howtoforge.com/creating_a_local_yum_repository_centos)

Comment: Nice. Looks like I'm not the only one. Came across the following when I googled for 'centos yum disable cache hostfile': http://www.dbaglobe.com/2009/12/how-to-disable-yum-faster-mirror-plugin.html Gonna try it, if it works I'll accept.